# Can not install kivy

Tags: python, installation, kivy

python v 2.7, linux mint. I keep getting this error message when I attempt to pip install kivy .. "Command "python setup.py egg_info" failed with error code 1 in /tmp/pip-build-jI7YZC/kivy/

```
$ pip install kivy
Collecting kivy
  Using cached Kivy-1.10.0.tar.gz
    Complete output from command python setup.py egg_info:
    Using distutils

    Detected Cython version 0.24.1
    Using this graphics system: OpenGL
    WARNING: A problem occurred while running pkg-config --libs --cflags gstreamer-1.0 (code 1)

    Package gstreamer-1.0 was not found in the pkg-config search path.
    Perhaps you should add the directory containing `gstreamer-1.0.pc'
    to the PKG_CONFIG_PATH environment variable
    No package 'gstreamer-1.0' found


    WARNING: A problem occurred while running pkg-config --libs --cflags sdl2 SDL2_ttf SDL2_image SDL2_mixer (code 1)

    Package sdl2 was not found in the pkg-config search path.
    Perhaps you should add the directory containing `sdl2.pc'
    to the PKG_CONFIG_PATH environment variable
    No package 'sdl2' found
    Package SDL2_ttf was not found in the pkg-config search path.
    Perhaps you should add the directory containing `SDL2_ttf.pc'
    to the PKG_CONFIG_PATH environment variable
    No package 'SDL2_ttf' found
    Package SDL2_image was not found in the pkg-config search path.
    Perhaps you should add the directory containing `SDL2_image.pc'
    to the PKG_CONFIG_PATH environment variable
    No package 'SDL2_image' found
    Package SDL2_mixer was not found in the pkg-config search path.
    Perhaps you should add the directory containing `SDL2_mixer.pc'
    to the PKG_CONFIG_PATH environment variable
    No package 'SDL2_mixer' found


     Traceback (most recent call last):
       File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
       File "/tmp/pip-build-BWSdZv/kivy/setup.py", line 934, in <module>
         version=get_version(),
       File "/tmp/pip-build-BWSdZv/kivy/setup.py", line 47, in get_version
         ['git', 'rev-parse', 'HEAD']
       File "/home/jq/anaconda/lib/python2.7/subprocess.py", line 567, in check_output
         process = Popen(stdout=PIPE, *popenargs, **kwargs)
       File "/home/jq/anaconda/lib/python2.7/subprocess.py", line 711, in __init__
         errread, errwrite)
       File "/home/jq/anaconda/lib/python2.7/subprocess.py", line 1343, in _execute_child
         raise child_exception
     OSError: [Errno 2] No such file or director
```

here is the whole log

Comment: which operating system?

Comment: Linux mint 18.2 Cinnamon 64-bit

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use alternative method to install kivy on Linux MINT:

1. First install the ppa package.

   ```
   sudo add-apt-repository ppa:kivy-team/kivy
   ```
2. Then Update all the packages

   ```
   sudo apt-get update
   ```
3. Now use following commands

   ```
   sudo apt-get install python-kivy
   sudo apt-get install python3-kivy
   sudo apt-get install python-kivy-example
   ```

I think that's all.